# How to customize Qt Message Handler on Android

Tags: android, qt, debugging

I'm using `qSetMessagePattern()` to customize the log formatting of a Qt application. On Windows, `qDebug()` outputs exactly what I expect, but on Android it adds some information before.
For example

```
qSetMessagePattern("[D] %{message}");
qDebug("Debug test");
```

Windows output:

```
[D] Debug test
```

Android output:

```
D/Qt  (30070): ..\project\filename.cpp:521 (void Class::method()): [D] Debug test
```

I've tried making a custom handler (and installing it with `qInstallMessageHandler()`), but I don't know how the message handler should output debug information on Android

**The question**: How to make Android message handler to stop prepending that information, or how to write a custom message handler for Android.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the code of the default message handler for android, and formatting is hardcoded, so I write a similar version:

```
#include <android/log.h>

static void android_message_handler(QtMsgType type,
                                  const QMessageLogContext &context,
                                  const QString &message)
{
    android_LogPriority priority = ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG;
    switch (type) {
    case QtDebugMsg: priority = ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG; break;
    case QtWarningMsg: priority = ANDROID_LOG_WARN; break;
    case QtCriticalMsg: priority = ANDROID_LOG_ERROR; break;
    case QtFatalMsg: priority = ANDROID_LOG_FATAL; break;
    };

    __android_log_print(priority, "Qt", "%s", qPrintable(message));
}
```

And installed it with:

```
qInstallMessageHandler(android_message_handler);
```